# Decide which line segment comes first

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Given a point `p` and two disjoint (no intersection, not even at endpoints) line segments `l1` an`l2`, return the line segment which is "in front" (the one that covers the other from `p`'s perspective). It will always be the case that one covers the other.

My current approach would be creating two triangles with the line segments and `p`. The triangle which doesn't contain a point of the other line segment is in front.

Three Examples:

[image: Three examples (they are to be looked at separately)]

Left example `OQ` is in front, middle one `TU` is in front, right one `VW` is in front.

This operation is critical in my application which is why I value simplicity, it must be correct in any case.

Comment: I suggest you research the math for this first. Learn how to do the computations by hand. Then the code should be straight forward.

Comment: Tip: You probably need to do calulations with vectors

Comment: In front of what? You want  a line that is in front of point but horizontally or vertically?

Comment: @LuaiGhunim Two line segments are given, one line segment will be in front of the other, the problem is deciding which one is in front (from the perspective of point `p`) of the other.

Comment: Thar's not difficult but you need to tell me what you consider as `front`, look in your example,(v,w) is in front of (z,g) or (o,q) is in front of (m,n)?

Comment: _"Please try to make comments more constructive"_ --- I could say the same thing about your question. I mean, this is ancient computer graphics basics, you could just google it. Nor is SO meant to have this kind of question and discussion.

Comment: @Mörre computer vision is one of the biggest challenge in A.I ,how is it ancient?

Comment: @LuaiGhunim **THIS** problem is "ancient"! Ridiculous! "Computer vision", really???

Comment: @LuaiGhunim Google it, this problem has been around for over 50 years. I'm NOT going to teach you how to use a search engine to find solutions to standard problems in computer graphics (not "computer vision").

Comment: this is a math question, not a programming one.

Comment: @Mörre Your argument about this being a simple problem could be used to delete every beginner's question, please don't discourage such questions as long as they are being asked in a clear way and haven't been asked before.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Programming and math do have some common ground, good observation. If your argument was valid then lots of questions (and their tags which exist for a reason) should be closed. Please don't discourage questions which have mild overlap with math as such matters are unavoidable in realistic programming scenarios.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: The `algorithm` tag is for just such problems: things we want to code Real Soon Now, but the current problem is the algorithm, not the implementation.

Comment: The problem with this question is not the overlap between programming and math. The problem is that you have not demonstrated that you understand the math and can focus on the programming.

Comment: Too broad ??? Is this a joke ??

Comment: 1) Make sure the two segments are oriented the same way around P. F.i. MN and OQ. 2) The sign of the area of MNO gives you the answer (and is the same as that of QON).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice knowing the math does not yield a robust and efficient solution in code as is often the case when implementing algorithms.

Comment: @AnnaVopureta knowing the math is a good place to start

Answer (score 3):

Consider a ray that starts from `P` and passes through one of the other four points. If the ray intersects the other line segment before reaching the point, then that point (and hence the line segment that contains that point) is behind the other line segment. One the other hand, if the ray intersects the other line segment after reaching the point, then that point is in front.

Consider your first example:

[image]

The blue rays don't intersect the other line segment, so they don't determine the ordering of the segments.  The green ray reaches `O` before intersecting `MN`, so `O` is in front of `MN`. The red ray intersects `OQ` before reaching `N`, so `N` is behind `OQ`.

Comment: This approach is not robust and inefficient, computing intersections should (and can) be avoided.